# How to disable sysrq on UART

Tags: pi-4, serial, uart, serial-console

I am trying to talk to a device over serial (ttyAMA0 or serial0) and it works, but sometimes I get the following TX from my rpi4, which crashes the device I talk to:

```
[22763.820857] sysrq: HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
```

I have already disabled shell over serial with `raspi-config`.
In the `/boot/config.txt` I added the following lines:

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=uart0
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

Is there some way to disable that or do I have to use another UART? And what causes sysrq to appear on UART?

EDIT: I also don't have `console=serial0, 115200` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. I also tried stopping  `serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`, but that also didn't help.

Comment: Ultimatively, it came down to this command: `sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed not only the serial console problem, but also the permissions on ttyAMA0 by disabling this service:

`sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`